# Android getString() with multilingual not working

Tags: android, localization, multilingual, android-7.0-nougat

I've create a short test Application with the following pre conditions:

My Smartphone run on 7.0 (and up). I've setup multiple languages in my settings `English (United States)` & `Deutsch (Deutschland)`.

### This is my App setup:

`compile-, target-, min-SdkVersion 24`

`String-Resources`:

[image]

The content from `strings.xml` (`"default"`) is:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Test</string>
    <string name="test">default</string>
</resources>
```

And the content from `string.xml` (`values-en-rGB`) is:

```
<resources>
    <string name="test">GB Fallback!</string>
</resources>
```

The `MainActivity` have only a `onCreate()` with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String string = getString(R.string.test);
    Log.d("TestString", string);

    final LocaleList locaList = LocaleList.getDefault();
    for (int i = 0; i < locaList.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("AvailableLocale", locaList.get(i).toLanguageTag());
    }
}
```

When I run my `App` I expect the output from `"TestString"` is `GB Fallback!`. Why? Because Android 7.0 support [multilingual](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html). * (See update)

Instead of `GB Fallback!` I get always the default output. That means `default`.

The output from `AvailableLocale` is always up to date with the setup from my phone settings.

So. Why I got `default` from `getString(R.string.test)`. Do I miss understand something with the multilingual stuff from the Android docs?

### * Update

Why I claim I got `GB Fallback!`. The reason is the [multilingual](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html) feature. The documentation shows a nice table:
[image]
I will try it to map it to my situation:

(Sorry, my Image is wrong. I don't mean `de-GB`. It's `en-GB` of course)
[image]

So, what is wrong here?

Comment: for that, you need to change your device default language from English to Deutsch

Comment: This is totally wrong. Why should I got `GB Fallback` (which is located in `en-rGB`) when I set my language to german (which should located in `de-*` or without prefix in just `de`)? That makes no sense!

Comment: this is actually correct... it will always fall-back to the default strings (manually attempting to define a fallback option is rather "totally wrong" - because the default is the fallback option already). while the `final` keyword might only add more confusion.

Comment: When you lang order is 1) de, 2) en_US, it will never fallback to en_GB because it is not in your language list. en_US is more specific and will not match en_GB. Less spedific is the fallback. For example: de_AT and de_DE are more specific. If anyone has de_CH as a preference they get de translation in case they are present and they do not have de_AT or de_DE set as a preference